# SQL two rows in one

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql database looks like this below:

Table Match:

```
id     | homeTeamId | guestTeamId
------ | ---------- | ----------
1      | 1          | 2
------ | ---------- | ----------
2      | 13         | 9
```

Table Team:

```
id     | Name 
------ | ------ 
1      | Arsenal London      
------ | ------ 
2      | Manchester City     
------ | ------ 
9      | Tottenham    
------ | ------ 
13     | Aston Villa
```

Now I want to make a query, which return all matches with my teamnames. 
My output should look like this:

```
id     | homeTeamId | guestTeamId | hometeam       | guestteam
------ | ---------- | ----------- | ---------------| ---------
1      | 1          | 2           | Arsenal London | Manchester City
------ | ---------- | ----------- | ---------------| ---------
2      | 13         | 9           | Aston Villa    | Tottenham
```

So, how can I do this? I tried a lot with inner joins, left joins, group by,.... But the problem is, that I need two joins on one table and give an alias for the same column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Here's one using multiple `joins`:

```
select m.id, m.hometeamid, m.guestteamid, t1.name hometeam, t2.name guestteam
from match m 
    join team t1 on m.hometeamid = t1.id
    join team t2 on m.guestteamid = t2.id
```